# Using Google Map API for Business with Openlayers

Tags: openlayers-2, google-maps-api

Has anyone used the paid version of Google Map API (for business) with OpenLayers? I am currently using the free version and wonder what the difference is, from both the end user and developer perspectives?

I've read the terms on Google site but couldn't find anything specific enough for working with OpenLayers. For example, does it support higher zoom level with clearer satellite imagery?

Thanks!

Comment: Google Maps API for Business is only designed to work with Google Products and Services (Fusion Tables, Map Engine etc) not third party applications or open source software (they do not support it)

Comment: Good to know - I have an app using OpenLayers+Google Maps that requires login, and was told that I need to pay for the Google API.  Wasn't sure what I'd get for the $.

Answer (score 2):

The licence says that you cant use free licence if you use google maps for sites that are not accessible to general public. As for technical differences, there arent any in terms of data quality. It costs about 10000usd or 8000eur per year.

I had an idea of using google maps to create a simple gis by using fusion tables services to render other data, but there are limits as well (only 4 fusion tables layer at a time), so i think best way to do it is to use one of the open source librairies, openlayers or leaflet, which also support google maps layer (via free api again) but add additional functionality you typically need to build a webgis.

Comment: Thanks both for the feedback.  I am in fact using OpenLayers engine with Google map/satellite imagery, all behind a login.  Do I still need to pay google that way?

Comment: Yes, in fact you have to: https://developers.google.com/maps/terms see section 9.1.1

Answer (score 0):

If you already using OpenLayers map engine there is no need to add the second map engine of google. I did this on past and now I splitting what should be done in one and other. Loading both engines is heavy and will cause problems. OpenLayer for example get looked at basic google.maps.Map resolutions, zoom levels from 0 to 18( or 22 ) if I remember well.

I did not used the paid version but I was unable to change resolutions( number of zoom levels ) when it has google maps layers attached on map.
In my case I tried to reduce the zoom levels to six. But OpenLayers replied wrong levels to google.maps API. Also with google you will be looked with map mercator projection.

If you need google stuff, drop OpenLayers and stay with only one engine.

Answer (score 0):

google maps premium plan does not offer any differences in the resolution nor zoom levels. Main difference is in the limits of the standard licence vs the premium one.

https://developers.google.com/maps/pricing-and-plans/